# MySQL Subquery returned more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I cannot figure out why this is not working.  Basically, I am running a subquery to count all rows of `p.songid WHERE trackDeleted=0`.  The subquery works fine when I execute it by itself, but when I implement I get "subquery returned more than 1 row".

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty,
(SELECT COUNT(p.songid)
 FROM  songs s
 LEFT JOIN users u
 ON u.id = s.userid
 LEFT JOIN posttracks p
 ON s.songid = p.songid
WHERE p.trackDeleted=0
 GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
 LIMIT 25)
AS trackCount
 FROM  songs s
 LEFT JOIN users u
 ON u.id = s.userid
 LEFT JOIN posttracks p
 ON s.songid = p.songid
WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
 GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
 LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, a sub-query can't return more than one row, as this makes no sense. You only expect one value to be returned - `COUNT(p.songid)` - yet you GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted, which will make it return multiple rows, and multiple counts of `p.songid`.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to create a new column with the track count of all the tracks WHERE deletedTrack=0.  How else would I go about this?

Comment: Just remove the GROUP BY and the LIMIT clauses from the sub-query

Comment: If I do that it's returning the same value for each row.  I need it to be able to return the number of rows where tracksDeleted=0 for each songid.

Comment: first of all, you should do it anyways for the sub-query. Second, you should add another condition to the sub-query WHERE clause, limiting the sub-query to only when `s.songid` of the parent query equals the one in the sub-query, and has the same `s.timeSubmitted` (`WHERE p.trackDeleted=0 AND subS.songid=s.songid AND subS.timeSubmitted=s.timeSubmitted`). For that you need to re-alias your `songs` table inside the sub-query to some different alias, as it is the same of the parent query alias (on my example WHERE clause, I've used 'subS' as the new alias).

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way, a subquery in the SELECT statement like you have needs to return a single value since it is going to act like just another column in your select list. Since you have a `LIMIT 25` on yours, you're obviously expecting more than one value back, which is inocrrect for this usage.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to create a new column with the track count of all the tracks WHERE deletedTrack=0.  How else would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, your query is a mess. Not only is the subquery broken, but I'm pretty sure the `GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted ASC` isn't doing what you think think it does.  (Did you mean `ORDER BY` instead?)  It might help if you explained in words what you're trying to accomplish.

Anyway, I'm going to take a wild guess and suggest that *this* might be what you want:

```
SELECT
  u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle,
  s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty,
  COUNT(p.songid) AS trackCount
FROM songs s
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.userid
  LEFT JOIN posttracks p ON p.songid = s.songid AND p.trackDeleted = 0
WHERE paid = 1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
GROUP BY s.songid
ORDER BY s.timeSubmitted ASC
LIMIT 25
```

Edit: Fixed the `COUNT()` so that it will correctly return 0 if there are no matching tracks.